# C++ Heap: Assigning a pointer of a queue

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm playing with some examples of C++.

I try to give two classes access to the same queue.  This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class MessageQueue{
public:
    std::queue<int> m_queue;
};

class A_Object{
public:
    MessageQueue *ToMQ=0;
};

class B_Object{
public:
    MessageQueue *FromMQ=0;
};

void connectMQ(MessageQueue *original, MessageQueue *source, MessageQueue *destination);

void connectMQ(MessageQueue *original, MessageQueue *source, MessageQueue *destination){
    source = original;
    destination = original;
    // source and destination has the same addresses as original  
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    MessageQueue *messageQueue1Send;
    messageQueue1Send = new MessageQueue();

    A_Object a_Object;
    B_Object b_Object;

    connectMQ(messageQueue1Send,    a_Object.ToMQ, b_Object.FromMQ);
    // at this point the addresses of a_Object.ToMQ and b_Object.FromMQ dont show to the same adress on the heap like messageQueue1Send
    
    messageQueue1Send->m_queue.push(10);

    int value = b_Object.FromMQ->m_queue.front();

    cout << "value="<< value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After the method `connectMQ`, the addresses are not the same. It looks like the assignments of `connectMQ` are only valid inside the method body.

How to make the assignments in the right way, to resolve this error and access only the heap address, not the stack?

Comment: `source = original;` and `destination = original;` don't do what you think they do. Are you aware that in C++ function parameters get passed by value, and do you know what "passing by value" means?

Comment: Try and avoid using pointers in C++ when you can use references instead. Use `nullptr` instead of C-isms like `ptr* x = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
void connectMQ(MessageQueue *original, MessageQueue *source, MessageQueue *destination){
     
    source = original;
    destination = original;
    // source and destination has the same addresses as original  
}
```

you have *copies* of the input arguments. Changing source does nothing to the callers variables. If you want to change `source` and `destintation` then do this

```
void connectMQ(MessageQueue *original, MessageQueue **source, MessageQueue **destination){
     
    *source = original;
    *destination = original;
    // source and destination has the same addresses as original  
}
```

called like this

```
 connectMQ(messageQueue1Send,    &a_Object.ToMQ, &b_Object.FromMQ);
```